# Cloudflare returning 400 bad request on repeated Authorization header

Tags: php, laravel, cloudflare

My project is in Laravel 8.
Recently we have moved to another instance on aws. The problem is in android side, `Authorization` token is repeated in request and I am getting `400 bad request` from cloudflare.

On postman I tested as follows:

**With single Authorization header I am getting proper response**

[image: With single Authorization header]

**With repeated Authorization header, I am getting 400 Bad Request from cloudflare**

[image: With repeated Authorization header]

Please suggest me the ways to get rid of this response, apart from releasing another APK on playstore.